# xcode - Run the code in Terminal

Tags: python, xcode, macos

I am coding a Python 2.7 script in Xcode. When click on build and run I get the confirmation it was successful, however nothing is shown. I would like to see the output the script in a terminal window.

Is there a way to get Xcode doing that for me, instead of having to open it on my own?

Answer (score 0):

You can open Terminal from Application folder, then just enter

> python gameover.py

If you don't have python in your path install it with

> brew install python

If you are new to brew, install it from here http://brew.sh/

Here is a duplicate question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131375/how-run-a-py-python-script-in-xcode with same result

May I suggest you to try https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/ ?

Comment: I would like to get Xcode doing that for me. Is there a way?

Comment: I updated the answer. I looked though the web, but didn't find a direct solution.